# Lazy evaluation function decorator

Tags: python, meta-programming, lazy

Suppose I have some expensive function `expensive_computation` which takes a long time to compute but it always returns the same value.

I want to avoid paying the cost of computing this function because it may never be called.

Here is my solution to this, is there a more obvious or clean way to do it? Or maybe even some function from the standard library?

```py
def lazy(function):

  internal_state = None

  def lazy_evaluation():
    nonlocal internal_state
    if internal_state is None:
      internal_state = function()
    return internal_state

  return lazy_evaluation

@lazy
def expensive_computation():
  print("Working ...")
  return "that was hard"

print(expensive_computation())
print(expensive_computation())
```

Which prints:

```
Working ...
that was hard
that was hard
```

Comment: Suppose this isn't real code, then it's undeniably off-topic here. Is only `lazy` up for review, and do you want any and all facets of your code reviewed? [Please ensure your question is otherwise on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Any review concerning the implementation of `lazy` or the use of such a construct is what I'm looking for. I'm not sure what you mean by "real code", it's some working code, where I replaced every piece on which I don't want advice on by dummy code (I don't need advice on the content of `expensive_computation`, that's why I don't provide its implementation).  On the other hand, the implementation of `lazy` is the exact one I intend to use. I added the output to make clear what behaviour I expect (because I noticed the term "lazy evaluation" is actually broader than this use case).

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     if internal_state is None:
>       internal_state = function()
> ```

What if `function()` returns `None`?

---

> Or maybe even some function from the standard library?

[`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

Comment: So how do you change the code with regard to the first point if `None` is a valid return?

Comment: My function never return `None`, but in the general case I guess that you would just have a boolean marker beside the `internal_state`, so you can tell if the function has been evaluated or not, but that's just a guess and probably not the best solution either. 
Concerning the cache solution I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, the obvious approach would be to use a separate Boolean variable. An alternative, which I consider hackier, would be to not have a separate variable for `internal_state` at all: `result = function(); function = lambda () => result; return result`